# Creating an orphan branch but still be able to merge from another origin

Tags: git, github, git-merge

Here is the scenario.

I have an `origin1` remote with a `develop` branch. This branch contains lots of commits and history.

From that branch, I want do create an orphan branch (`develop`) into `origin2` remote. (origin1/develop -> origin2/develop without any the history).

Is it possible to keep `origin2/develop` orphan **without** inheriting the history when I merge changes from origin1/develop into origin2/develop?

Comment: Does `origin2` have any other branches?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice No. it doesn't.

Comment: Without any other branches, calling a branch an "orphan" is meaningless.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Why would it be meaningless? I don't want to inherit the history from origin1/develop.  So it doesn't matter if there is one branch or thousand branches. That's not the point

Comment: The whole point of a merge is to inherit the history of another branch. If you don't want the history you can't do just a merge.

Comment: By definition the word "orphan" compares two branches without two branches, the word doesn't apply.

Comment: But is there a way to create a whatever branch without inheriting any history from the other remote (origin1) without creating an orphan branch? And still be able to get merge only the latest changes from that?

Comment: A new orphan branch has no files, so there is nothing to apply changes to.

Comment: I think we need to back up. Can you give a concrete example to illustrate what you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

If your repository has no other branches, calling the only branch an "orphan" is meaningless.

**Original answer:**

After a merge, a branch gets all of the history of the branch merged into it. So if you do

```
$ git checkout --orphan develop
$ git merge origin1/develop
```

in `origin2`, `origin2/develop` will contain all of the commits from `origin1/develop`.

The idea of an "orphan" branch only makes sense if `origin2` has other branches. In which case, `origin2/develop` will be orphaned from all of these branches. However, it will not be orphaned from `origin1/develop` nor any branches because you did a merge.